# Uploaded image is not display in Moodle

Tags: tinymce, moodle

I create a block in **Moodle**, where I can add questions and answer. While add question I upload images to the question. I am using **tinymce editor** here.

[image]

Thats ok.

While login as student. In student section the image is not displaying. But the name/description of the image (in `alt` parameter) is displayed here.

I inspect the section and it shows :

```
<img style="max-height:30px;" src="http://mysitedotcom/brokenfile.php#/5/user/draft/103179932/amazon_river.jpg" alt="amazon_river.jpg" width="200" height="100">
```

**How can I make the image display in student section?**

In teacher section while I edit the question the image is displayed in **tinymce editor.** So I am sure that the image is saved, but in student section it is not displaying.

Please help me....

**EDIT**

In database the question is saved as:

```
<p>Find this?</p>
<p><img src="http://mysitedotcom/draftfile.php/5/user/draft/52307129/amazon_river.jpg" width="200" height="100" /></p>
```

My moodle version is 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've gone through all the steps listed here:
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms#Simple_use

This includes calling file_prepare_standard_editor to copy any files into the draft area before showing the form, file_postupdate_standard_editor to copy files out of the draft area once the form is saved and implementing the block_myblock_pluginfile() function in your lib.php to authenticate all file requests.

Comment: Please look the Edit in my post. The question (including image) is saved in db. I try to display the value(hard code) both in teacher section and student section. In teacher section it is displaying, but in student section the text is only displaying image is not.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It would be nice if you share how you solved the issue. - @DeepuSasidharan